# Recursively opening directories UNIX/C

Tags: c, unix, recursion

I am trying to open the directories recursively and print some metadata about the files. However, the directories does not open. the dir name is correct and I am stumped why the opendir is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
void scan( const char *dir) // process one directory
{
  DIR *dp;
 struct dirent *de; 
 struct stat sbuf;
 dp = opendir( dir);
if( dp == NULL) 
{ 
   //perror( dir);
   printf("Cannot open directory: %s\n",dir);
    return;
 }
 // printf("%s\n",dir);
while(1)
 {
    //const char * d_name;
    de = readdir( dp);
    if( de == NULL)
             break;//Empty Directory

//d_name = de->d_name;
    //printf("d_name: %s\n",d_name);
    if(strcmp(de->d_name,"..") == 0 || strcmp(de->d_name,".") == 0)
           continue;
 //AT THIS POINT ALL .. AND . SHOULD BE SKIPPED AND CONTINUED.
    char abs_path[1024];
      snprintf(abs_path,1024,"%s/%s",dir,de->d_name);
    if(stat(abs_path, &sbuf))
    {
          //perror(abs_path);
          printf("Error in stat %s\n",abs_path);
          continue;
    }
    if( S_ISDIR(sbuf.st_mode))
    {
           printf( "d\t");
           printf( "%lu\t%s\n", (unsigned long) sbuf.st_size,abs_path);
           scan(abs_path);
    }
    else
    {
          //printf("d_name tab: %s\n",d_name);
          printf("\t");
          printf( "%lu\t%s\n", (unsigned long) sbuf.st_size,abs_path);
    }

 }
 closedir(dp);
}
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if( argc > 1)
  for( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) 
    scan( argv[i]);
  else
    scan(".");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ALWAYS check the result of system calls like opendir and, if failed, get the errno and print/log it to find out what happened.

Comment: I agree with @MartinJames; there are many things which could be going wrong. The most obvious is permissions.

Comment: even in perror it simply says the file or directory does not exists

Comment: @SarathBabuTamminani, perhaps the specified directory does not exist?  What measures have you taken to validate the 'dir' character string?

Comment: I've just built and run this code and it seems to recursively list directories fine. You'll probably need to be more specific about the errors you're seeing to get more help.

Comment: If you use an initial path of "something.../", the trailing `/` may mess up the concatenation.

Comment: @chux How does a trailing `/` mess up concatenation? `/foo/bar/` is the same as `/foo/bar` is the same as `/foo//bar` see e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and

Comment: @Brandin OP is having _some_ issue.  I agree the _majority_ of varieties of Unix do treat non-leading `"//"` and `"/"` the same, as you suggest.  The link you supplied refers to how a shell interprets the string.  The question here, thought not given much detail, is that the OP is having a problem in C and corner cases could be explored.